# Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": Program too complex: too big jump offset

Tags: web-services, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm developing an Mobile Application using MobileFirst Platform V7.1. The backend team is giving the raw data for which I have to do the entire business logic from my adapter side. Hence I have to do many loopings of my code to achieve the expected result. I successfully completed doing so and able to deploy the HTTP adapter on my local machine and get the result. The problem is when I deply the same adapter on my development and production MobileFisrt(MFP) server I'm ended up with the following error

> Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39":
>   Program too complex: too big jump offset
>   (2016-02-21T20:29:42.632Z/956ab824e6aec09f6cf70e1a1f0792d5da096574/PCRF_WS-impl.js#5)

Can anyone please help me to resolve this error as it become a red flag to host my application as we are nearing the application release date.

Comment: You did not provide anything though...

Comment: You’ll have to provide us with some code, because we can’t tell from this description why it’s complaining.on the other hand, you mentioned "Hence I have to do many loopings of my code to achieve the expected result" I think it is look like a bug. you have to reduce loopings of code

Answer (score 0):

Questioner mentioned:

> Hence I have to do many loopings of my code to achieve the expected result

it is look like a bug. you have to reduce loopings of code .for  this error:

```
Encountered code generation error while compiling function "39": Program too complex: too big jump offset
```